# how secure is data on qgis?

Tags: qgis, security

What is the safety guarantee using the QGIS platform for data storage?
I want no data loss and easy access to data when stored. Can passwords be used to safeguard data and how do I give permissions to users?

Comment: The actual question is unclear, and the body contains two out the questions which might be restatements of the main question, or not. Are you asking about password protection, likelihood of data loss, or vendor warranties? Please consider rewording.

Comment: I agree with Lee. The question doesn't really make sense as QGIS is not a platform for data storage. Danny, maybe you misunderstand the function/purpose of QGIS?

Comment: thanks matt and lee. i'm actually a rookie on this and just beginning my foray into Qgis. so pardon me guys for the poorly structured question.

Comment: i would really appreciate if one of you could be my personal coach on this. thanks guys

Answer (score 3):

From the [user guide](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/appendices/appendices.html#gnu-general-public-license): *"...there is no warranty for this free software."*

As QGIS is a user application, you should make sure you have appropriate backups. You can use external applications (e.g. archive / "zip") applications for encryption and backup, and the security of the result depends on those applications, not on QGIS.

Comment: FYI The 'backups' should be at least on two separate systems (windows/linux) that do not share the same physical location (in-case of fire/flood/). Synced cloud storage helps out these days (dropbox, amazon s3). This applies to general IT data/software not just QGIS.

Comment: And also stated in the license (GPL)  "15. Disclaimer of Warranty.

THERE IS NO WARRANTY FOR THE PROGRAM, TO THE EXTENT PERMITTED BY APPLICABLE LAW. EXCEPT WHEN OTHERWISE STATED IN WRITING THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND/OR OTHER PARTIES PROVIDE THE PROGRAM “AS IS” WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EITHER EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. THE ENTIRE RISK AS TO THE QUALITY AND PERFORMANCE OF THE PROGRAM IS WITH YOU. SHOULD THE PROGRAM PROVE DEFECTIVE, YOU ASSUME THE COST OF ALL NECESSARY SERVICING, REPAIR O

Answer (score 3):

As an addition to BradHards answer that there are no tools for backup/permissions/secuirty from the Qgis side:

Especially your last point, permissions to users, is a typical scope for databases without local access. The normal usecase is to setup a database that takes care of the user-roles, security and backup and then connect it to your applications via direct connect or a web service.

On the security side, you have many things up to row-level security (that a single user can only see single entries meant for him/her) and overall data encryption.

On the prevention of data loss you have checksums for datapages that will tell you when there was a corruption like a rotten bit.

And on the backup side you have different forms of backup up to versioning, point in time recovery, server replication and more.

That being said with the previous examples apply to Postgres as database(and likely for the other big databases, that i´m not familiar with), which is the standard open source for geodata, you will usually don´t try to achieve this for your local application. Just set up a database when it is important and you want to take care of all these matters together.